# Java Comparator syntax?

Tags: java, comparator

I'm a bit confused of the following code snippet:

```
PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return counts.get(b) - counts.get(a);
    }
});
```

The constructor of PriorityQueue is `PriorityQueue​(Comparator<? super E> comparator)` and `Comparator` is an interface.

My questions:

1. It seems that the code above combines the interface implementation and instantiation at once, how does it work?
2. How can it pass the `Comparator` instance itself without assigning it to a variable, or a name?

reference:
https://sp18.datastructur.es/materials/discussion/examprep05sol.pdf

Comment: 1. it's called anonymous class instance.

Comment: 1) [Anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). 2) Just the way the language works. You don't always need a variable. It's convenient.

Comment: Huge thanks guys wow I searched for hours and got no clue posting it and got replied within minutes. Such an amazing community!

Comment: It is expecting a object of type Comparator.When java compiles it,it  creates a separate class for the anonymous class and creates a object of it and passes it to the PriorityQueue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, `Comparator` is an anonymous inner class instance.